# Prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{3^n\cdot7\times10\times\cdots\times (3n+1)}=\frac{\pi\sqrt3}{2}+\frac32\ln(3)−4$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Prove $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{3^n\cdot7\times10\times\cdots\times (3n+1)}=\frac{\pi\sqrt3}{2}+\frac32\ln(3)−4$$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $4$ in the denominator?

Comment: The previous series was divergent, but would converge if the $(3n+1)$ in the denominator was replaced with $(3n+4)$.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The sum is approximately $0.36861747935349131298$ and has a closed form in terms of a hypergeometric function, but the sum given is approximately $4.3122428402397139076$.

Comment: The answer I get is $$-4+\frac32\log(3)+\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2$$ which agrees numerically with what I gave above.

Comment: This assumes that $7\times10\times\cdots\times(3n+1)=1$ for $n=1$ (empty product).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the functional identities for the $\Gamma$ function we have that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}(3k+1)=3^n\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n!}{3^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}(3k+1)}&=&\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{9^n\cdot \Gamma\left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{B\left(n+1,\frac{1}{3}\right)}{9^n}\\&=&\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(1-x)^n x^{-2/3}}{9^n}\,dx=\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{8+x}x^{-2/3}\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the last integral can be solved by using the substitution $x=y^3$, leading to:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n!}{3^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}(3k+1)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-y^3}{8+y^3}\,dy = -1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}\,\pi+\frac{3}{8}\,\log 3.\tag{2}  $$
If now we multiply both sides  of $(2)$ by $4$ we prove tha stated identity.

Comment: (+1) My answer is a bit different, but along almost identical lines. I scrapped it when your answer appeared, but now I notice that there is a small error here. Your product goes up to $3n+4$ instead of $3n+1$. I didn't notice until I evaluated your integral and got a different answer.

Comment: I posted and deleted my answer, just in case you don't feel like editing your answer ;-)

Comment: @robjohn: I just imagined that the right series should be like the one I wrote, since the product appearing in the denominator starts with $7\cdot\ldots$. Anyway, this is easy to fix if $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(3k+1)$ was intended, just waiting for the OP to explain that.

Comment: The answer matches mine if the $3/\sqrt2$ coefficient of $\pi$ is changed to $\sqrt3/2$, so I think the question is as written and the answer has a typo.

Comment: Your product starts at $4$ instead of $7$. This means your answer is $\frac14$ of the value in the question. Easily fixed.